# Аккордеон/добавление класса при клике и удаление при клике на другой элемент

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на элемент "аккордеон" необходимо добавить класс для иконки, чтобы она поворачивалась на 45%. Но класс добавляется к самому элементу, а не к иконке.

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.FAQ-items', function() {
    $('.FAQ-icon').removeClass('FAQ-icon__rotate');
    $(this).addClass('FAQ-icon__rotate')
  })
```

HTML

```
<div class="FAQ-items">
            <h3 class="FAQ-link FAQ-link-1">Из чего формируется конечная стоимость
              проекта?</h3>
            <a href="#" class="FAQ-icon first-icons">
              <img src="./img/Rectangle12(Stroke).svg" class="first-icon" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).find('.FAQ-icon').addClass('FAQ-icon__rotate');
```